# Laravel blade shows error when there is no dd(), but works with it

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-blade

I have code to check if there is user's id in pivot table, and if there is check if he upvoted or downvoted (1 or -1)
`{{ $post->votes->where('id', $user->id)->first()->pivot->vote }}`
But this for some reason won't work, even though it works in controller when i die and dump, or even in blade file when it is in dd(). Edit: The error says "Trying to get property 'pivot' of non-object". How can I fix this?

Comment: did you try yo dump`$post->votes->where('id', $user->id)->first()` ? seems like its empty

Comment: @devnullΨ It's not empty, I did try it. Like I said, in dd(...) it shows 1 (like it should have), but it can't work without dd()

Comment: do you iterate it through loop? add some more code

Comment: @devnullΨ In controller    
`$posts = Post::with(['user', 'category', 'favorites', 'votes'])->paginate(10);`     
And I send `$posts` to posts.blade.php where I iterate them `@foreach($posts as $post)`

Comment: dump `$posts` and check if every item of collection has pivot attribute and its not empty. I'm sure some of them are

Comment: There are some empty `$posts` "votes" relationships    
`#relations: array:4 [▼
          "user" => User {#1627 ▶}
          "votes" => Collection {#1942 ▼
            #items: []
          }
        ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some items of your collection must be empty, that's why you are getting the error. at first, you should check if you have votes with that condition

```
if ($post->votes->where('id', $user->id)->first()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

and then also check for `pivot` attribute, for example

```
$post = $post->votes->where('id', $user->id)->first();
if ($post && $post->pivot) {
    echo $post->pivot->vote;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if there are any votes first and then you can use `pivot->vote`, to achieve that in one line you can use [`optional`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-optional) helper method

```
{{ optional($post->votes->where('id', $user->id)->first()->pivot)->vote }}
```

Also make sure you have loaded `votes` relationship on `$post` from your controller

Comment: "Trying to get property 'vote' of non-object". I did load votes

Comment: Okay, extend the `optional` to include `pivot` property too and try it then, I've updated my answer with an example

Comment: I did try it and now it showed "Trying to get property 'pivot' of non-object"

Comment: When you extended `optional` to include `pivot` too it's throwing the same error?

Comment: Yup, same error but first time, only first time said 'votes' and second time said 'pivot'

Comment: Try doing `dd($post->votes->where('id', $user->id)->exists())` and tell us what value does it dump

Comment: I solved the problem, I marked the solution. Thanks anyway